# Radiation in nuclear power system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, nuclear-physics, radiation, nuclear-engineering

What are the 3 high level groups of sources of alpha, beta and gamma radiation in nuclear power systems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For beta and gamma  :  fission products ,
For alpha :  actinides after neutron capture without fission  such as  239Pu .